# Exchange of 2 json data values which has different keys

Tags: python, json, python-3.x

I want to exchange 2 json data's value. But keys of these datas are different from each other. I don't know how can I exchange data value between them.

**sample json1: A**

```
{
  "contact_person":"Mahmut Kapur",
  "contact_people": [
    {
      "email": "m@gmail.com",
      "last_name": "Kapur"
    }
  ],
  "addresses": [
    {
      "city": "istanbul",
      "country": "CA",
      "first_name": "Mahmut",
      "street1": "adres 1",
      "zipcode": "34678",
      "id": "5f61f72b8348230004f149fd"
    }
  ]
  "created_at": "2020-09-16T07:29:47.244-04:00",
  "updated_at": "2020-09-16T07:32:50.567-04:00",
}
```

**sample json2: B**

> The values in this example are: Represents the keys in the A json.

```
{
    "Customer":{
        "DisplayName":"contact_person",
        "PrimaryEmailAddr":{
            "Address":"contact_people/email"
        },
        "FamilyName":"contact_people/last_name",
        "BillAddr":{
            "City":"addresses/city",
            "CountrySubDivisionCode":"addresses/country",
            "Line1":"addresses/street1",
            "PostalCode":"addresses/zipcode",
            "Id":"addresses/id"
        },
        "GivenName":"addresses/first_name",
        "MetaData":{
            "CreateTime":"created_at",
            "LastUpdatedTime":"updated_at"
        }
    }
}
```

**The outcome needs to be:**

```
{
"Customer":{
    "DisplayName":"Mahmut Kapur",
    "PrimaryEmailAddr":{
        "Address":"m@gmail.com"
    },
    "FamilyName":"Kapur",
    "BillAddr":{
        "City":"istanbul",
        "CountrySubDivisionCode":"CA",
        "Line1":"adres 1",
        "PostalCode":"34678",
        "Id":"5f61f72b8348230004f149fd"
    },
    "GivenName":"Mahmut",
    "MetaData":{
        "CreateTime":"2020-09-16T07:29:47.244-04:00",
        "LastUpdatedTime":"2020-09-16T07:32:50.567-04:00"
    }
}
```

}

So the important thing here is to match the keys. I hope I was able to explain my problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code can do the work for you. I dont know if someone can make this code shorter for you. It basically searches for dict and list till the leaf level and acts accordingly.

```
a={
  "contact_person":"Mahmut Kapur",
  "contact_people": [
    {
      "email": "m@gmail.com",
      "last_name": "Kapur"
    }
  ],
  "addresses": [
    {
      "city": "istanbul",
      "country": "CA",
      "first_name": "Mahmut",
      "street1": "adres 1",
      "zipcode": "34678",
      "id": "5f61f72b8348230004f149fd"
    }
  ],
  "created_at": "2020-09-16T07:29:47.244-04:00",
  "updated_at": "2020-09-16T07:32:50.567-04:00",
}
b={
    "Customer":{
        "DisplayName":"contact_person",
        "PrimaryEmailAddr":{
            "Address":"contact_people/email"
        },
        "FamilyName":"contact_people/last_name",
        "BillAddr":{
            "City":"addresses/city",
            "CountrySubDivisionCode":"addresses/country",
            "Line1":"addresses/street1",
            "PostalCode":"addresses/zipcode",
            "Id":"addresses/id"
        },
        "GivenName":"addresses/first_name",
        "MetaData":{
            "CreateTime":"created_at",
            "LastUpdatedTime":"updated_at"
        }
    }
}
c={}
for keys in b:
    if isinstance(b[keys], dict):
        for items in b[keys]:
            if isinstance(b[keys][items], dict):
                for leaf in b[keys][items]:
                    if "/" in b[keys][items][leaf]:
                        getter=b[keys][items][leaf].split("/")
                        b[keys][items][leaf]=a[getter[0]][0][getter[1]]
                    else:
                        b[keys][items][leaf]=a[b[keys][items][leaf]]
            else:
                if "/" in b[keys][items]:
                    getter=b[keys][items].split("/")
                    b[keys][items]=a[getter[0]][0][getter[1]]
                else:
                    b[keys][items]=a[b[keys][items]]
    else:
        if "/" in b[keys]:
            getter=b[keys].split("/")
            b[keys]=a[getter[0]][0][getter[1]]
        else:
            b[keys]=a[b[keys]]
print(json.dumps(b,indent=4))
```

Comment: Thank u for reply. Now I'm going to consider how I can make this code more functional :) I think working time: n^3 :)